# ListView with RadioButton in ItemTemplate does not update SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Listview with RadioButtons inside the ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Choice1}" />
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Choice2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

It is possible to select the current item on the "background". But if I click a RadioButton the SelectedItem is not set.

[image]

Desired behavior: the ListViewItem is selected whenever a "childitem" is clicked. Like Outlook when you set a flag, the current mail is selected.

[image]

Do I have to bubble up the click event somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior comes from the fact, that the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`-Property of the `ListViewItem` is false in that case. While you are clicking the RadioButton, the RadioButton has the Keyboard-Focus.

**Solution**

Add a simple trigger like this

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
               </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

**Complete Sample**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding }">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Choice1}" />
                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Choice2}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**Note**

Be sure you choose the right TargetType (`ListViewItem`, `ListBoxItem` or `TreeViewItem`)

Hope this helps